# Problema com tamanho do repositório Git

Tags: git

Na empresa onde eu trabalho, eu estava utilizando o Git para salvar um sistema, onde três pessoas utilizam-se dele.

Depois de, por acidente, ser enviada uma pasta de imagens, fazer um `git pull` se tornou absurdo, visto que os dados baixados são quase 1.6GB.

Posteriormente, removemos essa pasta de imagens através do arquivo `.gitignore`. Porém, mesmo depois dessa alteração, o repositório continua com um tamanho muito grande.

Tenho algumas perguntas a fazer sobre isso:

- Como reduzir o tamanho de um repositório do Git (quando ocorre um acidente como o referido acima)?
- Existe alguma maneira de trazer um `git pull` ou um `git fetch`, ignorando alguns arquivos, como imagens e/ou vídeos (através de parâmetros ou coisa do tipo)?
- Por que, mesmo depois de deletado os arquivos grandes e adicionados no `.gitignore`, o Git continua gigante? Os ignorados (anteriormente adicionados) fazer parte do histórico?
- E, se "sim" para o histórico, há alguma maneira de deletar esse arquivos indesejados do histórico?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Provavelmente o que você quer é reescrever a história do seu repositório, o que pode ser problemático se não souber o que está fazendo (eu não sei :P). isto é feito com [`filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch). Um exemplo:

```
git filter-branch --tree-filter 'rm -rf path/file' HEAD
```

Pode ser que precise adaptações, conforme sua necessidade, para isto leia a documentação.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

É possível também eliminar um *commit* e fazer um `rebase` mas acho que seria mais complicado.

Comment: Isso deve ser feito apenas no clone, ou posso fazer isso também direto no repositório remoto?

Comment: Boa pergunta. Você terá que "replicar" isto para todos os repositórios onde este arquivo esteja presente. Enquanto existir o arquivo em algum repositório, haverá o risco desse arquivo "ressuscitar" no repositório quando for feito um *merge*. Eu não sei dar detalhes porque nunca fiz esta operação. Mudar a história é uma tarefa que pode parecer simples mas é complicada quando existem vários repositórios envolvidos. A modificação da história só é 100% segura se não há *clones*, *branches*, etc., o que é raro para quem usar Git. É bom ter um clone só para desfazer se algo der errado.

Comment: Estes comandos devem assegurar que o arquivo seja removido do remote: `rm -rf .git/refs/original/` `git reflog expire --expire=now --all` `git gc --prune=now` `git gc --aggressive --prune=now` `git push --all --force`.

Comment: Note que se o repositório com este arquivo foi clonado em outro lugar esta cópia local não será deletada. O ideal seria, depois de atualizar o remote, clonar novamente o repositório.

Answer (score 4):

Você pode fazer um *cherry-pick* e remover ou desfazer um *patch*.

[Aqui](http://gitready.com/intermediate/2009/03/04/pick-out-individual-commits.html) tem uma boa explicação sobre o cherry-pick e [aqui](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2318777/undo-a-particular-commit-in-git) tem uma questão respondida que se assemelha muito ao seu problema.

Sugiro muita calma nesta hora para não remover nada além do necessário.